# Exchange Lab - Home Router Configuration

Tags: router, exchange

Currently I'm using a TP-Link router, to configure access OWA externally through my router, what setting do I need to configure?

Right now, I configure a virtual server that points to my exchange virtual server internal IP and configure port triggering 443.

May I know what is missing with my configuration?

Comment: You haven't told us anything about what's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For OWA, port 443 is enough. Use port 443 to accept traffic for owa

Comment: The OP indicates he's done this, so this doesn't answer the question. That's not your fault though. The question is not well framed right now.

Comment: OP just would like to know if his configuration is correct, my anwser is for OWA, it is enough. This is a consult question.

Comment: Asking, *what is missing with my configuration?* is not merely asking for confirmation the configuration is correct; something's not working.